# open a submenu to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu with different points like that:

```
Point 1  
Point 2  
Point 3  
Point 4
```

and want to open a submenu if e.g. Point 2 is clicked. It should look like that:

```
                 Point 1
 Point 2    |    Sub-Point 1
            |    Sub-Point 2
            |    Sub-Point 3
            |    Sub-Point 4
            |    Sub-Point 5
                 Point 3
                 Point 4
```

what is the best way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: ve you tried something??... anyway bootstrap ve dropdown menu like this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can create your menu anyway you like really, all you need to do is position the navigation bar off the screen and then use jQuery to simply slide in and slide out using the Animate function, and also remove and add a class to determine if the menu should slide out or slide in. Hope this helps

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t5enfd2v/

Html

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="slidetoggle slideout" type="button">slide toggle</button>
```

CSS

```
.sidemenu {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: -85px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.slidetoggle').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('slideout')) {
            $('.sidemenu').animate({
                left: "+=85",
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('.slidetoggle').removeClass('slideout');
                $('.slidetoggle').addClass('slidein');
                //Done
            });
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('slidein')) {
            $('.sidemenu').animate({
                left: "-=85",
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('.slidetoggle').removeClass('slidein');
                $('.slidetoggle').addClass('slideout');
                //Done
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to hide a submenu, as I don't want it to slide in from "left of the screen", but like from the middle to the left of the screen?

Comment: The code I have provided above can be modified to slide any given element in and out via clicking on a class. For a submenu you would need to modify the code so it is generic for all cases.